# RecyclerView Not being Clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, onclicklistener

I have a `RecyclerView` Adapter. I have other `RecyclerView` Adapters too and they are being clicked with no issue. However, when I click one of the `RecyclerView` items the toast message doesn't show up. Why?

```
public class AttendanceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    //...
    //other overridden factory methods of RecyclerView Adapter and //Constructors  and data setting Methods 
    //...

    public class AttendanceListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView rollNo, name;
        ImageView isPreset;

        public AttendanceListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            // ...
            // Layout Items initialization
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"reyclerViewClicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT :

My itemView XML looks like this ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roll_no_in_attendance_single_item"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="1" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_in_attendance_single_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTeal"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="1" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/present_or_absent_toggle_in_attendance_single_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_check_circle_black_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorTeal"
            android:layout_weight="2"

            android:text="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: itemview is it custome view ? then please post your itemview xml code

Comment: Thanks I had mistaked for putting each item into scrollview , i have posted the itemView in the edit , Thanks bro you saved my day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved : I made a mistake (unknowingly) using ScrollView inside each item ,

One must not use Scroll View into

`RecyclerView`

item, because

`RecyclerView` 
Scrolls Itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing by below method create utility class for `RecyclerView` item click.

```
public class ItemClickSupport {

    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener;

    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        }
    };
    private View.OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                return mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener mAttachListener
            = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            }
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    };

    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support != null) {
            support.detach(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemLongClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }

    public interface OnItemLongClickListener {

        boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }
}
```

use it like this in your `activity` or `fragment`.

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
        // your code here
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"reyclerViewClicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

As shown in this [blog](http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks).

Comment: Why down vote? This is way around for `OnItemClickListener` for `RecyclerView` as he is trying to set listener on whole `itemView` not particular `View` inside `itemView`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have an `item_view.xml` file. And your main layout is `LinearLayout`. Just define an **id** for it.

```
public class AttendanceListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    LinearLayout rootView;
    TextView rollNo, name;
    ImageView isPreset;

    public AttendanceListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        rootView = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.root_view);
        rootView.setClickable(true);
        rootView.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ...
        // Layout Items initialization
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"reyclerViewClicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```